# Вывести слaгаемые используемые при расчёте числа.Python

Tags: python, while

Ну могу понять как вывести все участвующие в расчёте числа... Само решение у меня правильное, не могу вывести согласно образцу весь путь сложения....

Решение должно быть через "while"....

Пример:

Число: 10

Cложение чисел 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10

Мой код:

```
num = 1
summa = 1
x = int(input("Число: "))

while summa < x:
    num += 1
    summa += num

print("Сложение чисел", x//num, "+", num, "=", summa )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользовать аргументом `end` функции `print`, который отвечает за то, что будет в конце выводимой строки и переписать ваш код так:

```
num = 1
summa = 1
x = int(input("Число: "))

print(f"Сложение чисел: { num } ", end='')

while summa < x:
    num += 1
    summa += num
    print(f"+ {num} ", end='')

print(f"= {summa}")
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! !!!!

Comment: Очень рада, что смогла помочь=)